# CodeIgniter error in pagination: Your number of links must be a positive number

Tags: codeigniter

```
$config['num_links'] = 0;
```

or

```
$config['num_links'] = FALSE;
```

throws this error in Codeigniter:

**Your number of links must be a positive number.**

How to disable showing the numbers in pagination?

Because I just want **next** and **previous** like:

```
< >
```

and not:

```
< 1 2 3 4 5 >
```

How to solve this problem in Codeigniter?

Comment: try to comment out in library class Pagination
from
`// Render the pages`
to `// Kill double slashes.  Note: Sometimes we can end up with a double slash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$config['display_pages'] = FALSE;`